# Jquery validation for html checkboxes showing undefined

Tags: jquery, html, validation

```
    var gender= $("input:radio[name=gender]:checked").val();
    alert(gender);
    return;
    if (gender == "") {
    $("#gender_error").fadeIn();      
    return false;
    }
```

If i don't give any value i am getting the alert as undefined so how would i actually validate the check box so that if no check box is selected i should get empty value or null so that the error appears.Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the radio html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to take the value by giving name and using `''` as said by Somnath and like below

```
 $("input:radio[name='gender']:checked").val();
```

Then you can check like this

```
if(gender == '' || gender == 'undefined') {
  //do your work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u are missing`''`
 **Previous**:

```
 $("input:radio[name=gender]:checked").val();
```

**New:**

```
$("input:radio[name='gender']:checked").val();
```

Comment: just modified...@AwaisQarni

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var gender= $("input:radio[name='gender']:checked").val();
    alert(gender);
    return; //this would break the execution
    if (typeof gender === "undefined" || gender == "") {
      $("#gender_error").fadeIn();      
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
```

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SBUc4/